# How can I add go to the next slide in impress.js

Tags: javascript

impress.js is a new web presentation written using Javascript. I want to create custom events to go to the next page. For example, I might create a "Next" and "Previous" button.

The entire impress.js file is a function, calling `selectPrev();` from within the function will go to the next page. However, I'm not very good with Javascript, I don't know how to call `selectPrev();` from outside the function.

The file can be found here: https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/blob/master/js/impress.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, the whole file is inside a closure, and `selectNext` is local to that closure. Additionally, it is only used indirectly in the key listener, so getting it from there is also impractical.

Thus, without modifying the source, I do not see any easy way to get at `selectPrev/selectNext`.

Here is the message from a commit about six hours ago:

```
impressive refactoring of slide selection - getting closer to API
```

It seems the developer is planning to add a proper API soon. If you wait a little, there should be some standard, sanctioned and (hopefully) documented way to interact with `impress.js` programatically.

If you just want a quick hack, you could always have your button trigger a key event. If you're using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 38 }))
```

`38` will go to the next slide and `40` to the previous.

Answer (score 16):

impress.js has been updated since this question was asked.  It is now simply a case of calling  one of the following API methods:

```
impress().next();
impress().prev();
impress().goto(10);
```

I've added this in case anybody stumbles on this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment use [jmpress.js](http://shama.github.com/jmpress.js/#/about) instead. It's jQuery port of impress.js, and it has an API with *next* and *prev* methods, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

it works, if next-prev are in inside impress div

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    impress().next();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#prev').on('click', function(e){
    impress().prev();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```